# JIRA automation to resolve tickets

Tags: jira, prometheus-alertmanager

I was looking a way to create a JIRA automation that resolves an issue when an issue with the prefix "[RESOLVED] " created.

A bit of background, the issues are created through email from AlertManager. More specific Alertmanager sends a "[FIRING:1] SummarySample" issue to JIRA and some time after if the issue resolved itself sends a "[RESOLVED] SummarySample" issue and I need when the resolved issue created to resolve the firing issue.
I can imagine how to resolve this programmatically with variables but with the automation flow I don't know.

Can anyone help me ???
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an idea, you might try to use other issue's field, like component/label to capture name SummarySample. Once captured and your automation gets an event of creation for RESOLVED find relevant issue by this component or label field and just check it's description for containing [FIRING] prefix with condition operator.

Also, you probably might try to link resolved and firing issues on the beginning and then navigate to the relative issue through the link